# What rumors were Cersei and Qyburn talking about in "No One"?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

This question is for the 8th Episode of Season 6 of Game of Thrones.

In the episode "No One", we got to see Cersei standing in the gallery with the Mountain (Robert Strong) and Qyburn.

At the end of that scene Qyburn and Cersei discuss some "rumors". What are they? **Is there any clue about the rumors  in previous episodes?** If so I don't seem to remember.

Comment: See also [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131724/s6e08-what-was-it-that-cersei-and-qyburn-talked-about), where this question has already been asked and answered on another SE site.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think the answer given in that link is incorrect.  As I recall, Tyrian used the hidden wildfire in The Battle of the Blackwater.

Comment: @randal'thor there is contention about that answer. Its purely speculation at this point and last time I checked the speculation wasn't backed up by any sort of canonical or semi canonical source.

Comment: @kuhl Sure, I just thought the link might be useful if the OP hadn't seen it before.

Comment: @randal'thor yep. Just wanted to make sure everyone was clear that the other question didn't have a satisfactory answer (per the OP) yet.

Comment: @ChadMattox The answer isn't incorrect, it is simply not yet proven correct. I've yet to hear another possibility that addresses all of the elements I point to in my answer.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, I may be remembering wrong, I've read the books and watched the shows, and I don't remember the specifics of what happened where...but my point was that by my memory, this theory CANNOT be correct...it can not be proven later to be correct as Tyrion has already used the hidden wildfire at The Blackwater.  Unless there is more that Tyrion and his agents were unable to find, and that is what this theory is about.

Comment: @ChadMattox This show has already shown repeatedly that it ignores previous events or even plain old logic (stabbed in the gut and thrown in dirty canal? just sleep it off and you'll ready for parkour) whenever they seem fit. Moreover, if it isn't going to be wildfire, what is it going to be? Look at the quote by Jaime, look at Bran's vision in a previous episode, look at the whole dialogue between Cersei and Qyburn, etc.

Comment: @BCdotWEB when trying to answer a question with speculation, the fact that the has had plot holes in the past is not evidence for your answer. On the other post I provided several examples that were as likely. None of them are likely enough to turn into an answer without more info.

Comment: I can't remember which episode, but I'm going thru them now. But, I thought she might have discussed this with the Qyburn when they were waiting for The Mountain to wake up.Just wondering...

Comment: @ChadMattox: in addition, she already knew about the wildfire because it was her project before Tyrion took it over. Also, presumably she knew firsthand from Jamie why he killed the King, since she may be his closest confidant and are *spoiler* lovers. So it just doesn't add up IMO

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**What rumors were Cersei and Qyburn talking about in “No One”?**

We don't know yet.

**Is there any clue about the rumors in previous episodes?**

No, or maybe yes if we count Bran's vision a hint.

Bran does see a vision of green fire aka [wildfire](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wildfire), which is one of the most talked about rumors

[source: [bustle.com](http://www.bustle.com/articles/166447-whats-cerseis-rumor-on-game-of-thrones-the-little-birds-may-deliver-important-information), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/4ntdsc/everything_the_rumor/)].

Even the dialogue looks suitable to the rumor:

> **Cersei:** And? Was it just a rumor or something more?
>
> **Qyburn:** More. Much more.

From the same [bustle.com](http://www.bustle.com/articles/166447-whats-cerseis-rumor-on-game-of-thrones-the-little-birds-may-deliver-important-information) link, a few more suggestions for the rumor are:

> - Since Varys' little birds are known to travel all over the place, the rumor could have something to do with Essos. If that's the case, it could be about Daenerys' dragons — or the fact that her younger brother is working with Daenerys. Either way, intel on Daenerys is pretty powerful in itself, and maybe she'd contact the Mother of Dragons to form some sort of alliance.
> - But what if Cersei learned her brother had nothing to do with it, and was investigating the Tyrells for Olenna's part in the murder? If Cersei found out that the Tyrells killed Joffrey, after Margaery convinced Tommen to accept the High Sparrow and Lady Olenna abandoned her at King's Landing, her vengeance would be unparalleled. If she told Tommen that Margery had something to do with Joffrey's death, there's a chance he could turn against his wife — and the Faith of the Seven — which could lead to him securing the kingdom for his family once again.

But all three are just rumors for now, and the wildfire rumor seems more reasonable as her reaction was not filled with anger. As per her nature, if she got to know about Margery's involvement in his son's death she might have lost her mind and not waited this long to act. On the other hand she hates Tyrion and doesn't look like a person who would make an alliance with the Targaryens, as they are enemies of the Lannisters.

---

**Update:**

In GoT S06E10, we got to know that rumor was about:

> Wildfire

Comment: I was thinking about Tyrion as well, but finding out about the Tyrell's involvement seems plausible too.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not known what they were discussing.  There was no previous scene in which Cersei was shown asking Qyburn to investigate a rumor.  The dialogue between Cersei and Qyburn in "No One" (S06E08) was introducing a new mystery.

Comment: Maybe it's about wildfire. Wildfire is the only "no one" between rumors.

Answer (score 2):

In the books, there are rumors about wildfire stashed underneath King's Landing. If you recall Bran visions, there a few about some devastating explosion. King Aerys wanted stashed that wildfire in his time, but couldn't give the order to ignite them because Jamie "Kingslayer" Lannister killed him before. So the wildfire is there, waiting to be ignited. Remember, Cersei is stripped every time of more and more power, and will become desperate, and desperate people do crazy things, like setting a entire city on fire.

Comment: Along those same lines, a common theme of Cersei's character is short-sited actions which seem like great ideas at the time; it entirely within her character to order the ignition of a wildfire cache beneath the Sept of Baelor...which winds up igniting the rest of the hidden caches throughout the city.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to Qyburn's discussion with Cersei regarding Varys's little birds. They must have found the wildfire stashed underneath King's Landing.

Since he seemed quite satisfied (happy) when Cersei asked for it, so it cannot be about Daenerys' dragons since that would have made him and her uncomfortable (unhappy).

Regarding hints of wildfire:

1. Bran's vision in S06E06 in which the Mad King says "Burn them all" and we also see a green blast (most probably of wildfire only)
2. Tyrion says in S06E09 -

   > He had caches of wildfire hidden under the Red Keep, the Guildhalls, the Sept of Baelor, all the major thoroughfares.

Comment: For the person(s) downvoted this - I hope you watched #GOTSeasonFinale :D
The best episode ever